# Combining and exporting matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, format, export

I have 3 different matrices, which I am trying to compile as column matrices into a larger matrix. I then need to save this to a text file to use later on.

The matrices are (I just used random values for b and c, they don't match the matrices below, just for example):

```
  a=[1957; 1977; 1982; 1984; 1993; 2000; 2007]
  b=[30903; 25696; 23976; 22622; 19250; 12398; 9299]
  c=[68; 56.542; 52.758; 49.778; 42.358  27.281; 20.462]
```

What I have done is this:

```
 b=([a b c])
```

This gives me the matrix I want,

```
b =

         1957        30903           68
         1977        25696       56.542
         1982        23976       52.758
         1984        22622       49.778
         1993        19250       42.358
         2000        12398       27.281
         2007         9299       20.462
```

however when I try to save this as a text file using:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%d    %d    %.2f\r\n',b);
fclose(fid);
```

The columns are mixed up, and looks like this:

```
1957    1977    1982.00
1984    1993    2000.00
2007    30903    25696.00
23976    22622    19250.00
12398    9299    68.00
5.654234e+001    5.275760e+001    49.78
4.235835e+001    2.728098e+001    20.46
```

What can I do to retain the format I wanted?

Comment: Use this - `fprintf(fid, '%d    %d    %.3f\r\n',b');` instead. You were needed to transpose `b` and use `%.3f` I suppose to keep upto three decimal places.

Comment: I would recommend `.'` in general to not get the hermitian transpose, but otherwise it is correct, matlab works with column vectors.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this guys! I've been stuck on this for a good couple hours!

Comment: @patrik That is conjugate transpose and if we know that there's no complex number involved in the data, `'` should be fine. But agreed for a general case, an additional `.` works.

Comment: @Divakar Well, It is at least correct for this case, but I do never count on that data is always real. Even if this may have been the case sometime, you never know when you want to reuse code. It is like discarding your train ticket after the first control.

Comment: @patrik Well I don't want to carry my passport on a train that I know won't cross my country lines, but you are right, people can hijack it and take it across!

Comment: @Divakar Did not mean to sound that harsh, however, but I have found that in most cases I have benefitted on being a bit more general. Writing a matrix to file is after all a quite general application, that a user may want to do again. However it is highly unlikely that anyone would want the hermitian conjugate here. Even if someone actually would want it, he would never want to do it inside a "write to file" function.

Comment: @patrik You are talking about a general case and on that you can always defend yourself and on that I am with you. On a sidenote, the code won't give desired output in text file if `b` is complex. So if you are talking about a general case of involving complex numbers too, it would need more than just the transpose. It's all good though as it has worked out with OP! And I am sorry I was in a sort of a weird mood maybe earlier :) It's all great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dlmwrite('filename.extn',b,'newline','pc');
```

Use '-append' if you want to append the matrix details to the contents of an existing file.
Hope this works.